# Using javascript to check the next input radio after a delay, then loop back

Tags: javascript, html, loops, input, checked

I'm trying to find a minimal way to automatically cycle through input radios after a given delay and then loop back to the beginning using js.

In the HTML example below, 'slide1' is checked initially, then I'd like 'slide2' to be checked after 3 seconds, then 'slide3' etc. looping back to 'slide1' at the end.

Can anyone help me with this? Many thanks!

```html
<div id="slider">
 <div id="slider-content">
  <input checked type="radio" name="slider" id="slide1" autofocus />
  <input type="radio" name="slider" id="slide2" />
  <input type="radio" name="slider" id="slide3" />
  <input type="radio" name="slider" id="slide4" />
  <input type="radio" name="slider" id="slide5" />
  <input type="radio" name="slider" id="slide6" />
  <input type="radio" name="slider" id="slide7" />
  <input type="radio" name="slider" id="slide8" />
  <input type="radio" name="slider" id="slide9" />
  <input type="radio" name="slider" id="slide10" />
  <input type="radio" name="slider" id="slide11" />
  <input type="radio" name="slider" id="slide12" />
  <input type="radio" name="slider" id="slide13" />
  <input type="radio" name="slider" id="slide14" />
  <input type="radio" name="slider" id="slide15" />
  <div id="slides">
   <div class="img1"> </div>
   <div class="img2"> </div>
   <div class="img3"> </div>
   <div class="img4"> </div>
   <div class="img5"> </div>
   <div class="img6"> </div>
   <div class="img7"> </div>
   <div class="img8"> </div>
   <div class="img9"> </div>
   <div class="img10"> </div>
   <div class="img11"> </div>
   <div class="img13"> </div>
   <div class="img14"> </div>
   <div class="img15"> </div>
  </div>
  <div id="controls">
   <label for="slide1"></label>
   <label for="slide2"></label>
   <label for="slide3"></label>
   <label for="slide4"></label>
   <label for="slide5"></label>
   <label for="slide6"></label>
   <label for="slide7"></label>
   <label for="slide8"></label>
   <label for="slide9"></label>
   <label for="slide10"></label>
   <label for="slide11"></label>
   <label for="slide12"></label>
   <label for="slide13"></label>
   <label for="slide14"></label>
   <label for="slide15"></label>
  </div>
  <div id="slide-indicator">
   <div>
    <label for="slide1"></label>
    <label for="slide2"></label>
    <label for="slide3"></label>
    <label for="slide4"></label>
    <label for="slide5"></label>
    <label for="slide6"></label>
    <label for="slide7"></label>
    <label for="slide8"></label>
    <label for="slide9"></label>
    <label for="slide10"></label>
    <label for="slide11"></label>
    <label for="slide12"></label>
    <label for="slide13"></label>
    <label for="slide14"></label>
    <label for="slide15"></label>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not tested, but the following should work. You'll need to make sure this function stops recurring when the user interacts with the inputs.

```
function checkInputsLoop(start, end, current){
    setTimeout(() => {
        document.getElementById(`slide${current}`).checked = true;
        if (current === end){
            current = start;
        }
        // add logic to stop once user has touched the inputs
        checkInputsLoop(start, end, current);
    }, 3000)
};

checkInputsLoop(1, 15, 1);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for answering Richard. Is there a way to use getElementsByName since all the inputs have the same name? I'm still in the early stages of learning js and I'm struggling to implement the suggestion at the moment.

Comment: You can yes, it could even be a better solution, but there's a key difference. `getElementById` will return one element (the first it encounters with that id), `getElementsByName` will return a list of all elements with that name. You could just iterate over that list instead of having to track the index.